# Reactjs fetch data from API and append to url

Tags: reactjs, fetch

Hoping someone can help. I want to show all documents associated to a particular assetId using reactjs.

In my mind (correct me if i'm wrong), all i need to do is this...

1. Fetch the data from http://localhost:3000/api/v1/assets
2. Pass 'assetId' from above fetch and then fetch  http://localhost:3000/api/v1/documents?AssetId=${assetId}

I've constantly rewritten this code, but as i'm fairly new to react i'm getting myself mixed up quite a bit so I've stripped the code back to the first API call (this will fetch an array).

What would be the next step to get this working? Would i need to create another function and pass the assetId down via props? How would i go about that?

```
fetchDocumemts(){
   fetch("https://localhost:3000/api/v1/assets")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(
        response => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            assets: response.results,
            assetId: response.results.assetId
          });
        },
        error => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchDocuments()
}
```

Thanks

Gillian

Comment: Greetings and welcome to Stack Overflow! can you please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: setState takes a callback, call your second fetch in that callabck.

Comment: What is the first API call returning, is it an array? an array of object? Please be clear with your question so we can help.

Comment: Thanks @ravibagul91, i'll look into this :)

Comment: No problem @RohitKashyap, i've updated post to say it is an array.

Comment: So you want to make a request for each asset id inside the array?

Comment: Hi @RohitKashyap, yes, basically when i view an asset, there is a section to show its associated documents. The only thing connecting the asset and its documents is assetId.

Answer (score -1):

It actually fairly easy, And do not know why in comments suggested to call setState.
You just need to chain api calls.

```js
fetchDocumemts() {
  fetch("https://localhost:3000/api/v1/assets")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(
      response => {
        const promises = response.results.map(({
          id
        }) => this.fetchDocument(id));
        // Deleted your set state, you can save here your assets 
        return Promise.all(promises);
      }
    )
    .then(res => {
      // There you must have all documents, do not know what you to do with them
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        error
      });
    })
}

fetchDocument(id) {
  return fetch(`https://localhost:3000/api/v1/documents?Assetid=${id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchDocuments()
}
```

But there you need to know:

1. I do not know your api(**response structure** and if it is correctly working), so debug
2. `Promise.all` api
3. Better to change `async\await`

Comment: Thanks for this Talgat :) Will give this a go just now. Will let you know how i get on.